# Jetpack Compose structure

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a question

Now, for example, in the old days, we had different activities, we had different fragments
The code was divided into different files

For example, each of the 200 lines of code could be easily worked with
The ui code was completely separate in xml
There were logical codes in the fragment, and eventually things went in separate classes

Now with compose and mvvm
How does this happen?
How can the codes be divided?
Does the concept of fragmentation and activity still make sense?
In those architectures, we meant the high level of activity and fragment code
What can be replaced in compose?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using Activities and Fragments with Compose. If you don't want to do that you can use [Compose navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation). As for separation: it's the same as for every other piece of code. You organize code based on various good practices, one being separation of concerns. The language for defining the layout doesn't really matter.

Comment: In general, my goal of this question is to get the structure of the jetpack compose